# Is it worthwhile to add SSL encryption to game data traffic?

Tags: c++, ssl, winsock

I just wanted to know if I should bother encrypting game data traffic over TCP (of course the username/password is encrypted)?  I hear openSSL is good for this sort of thing.

Comment: You're sending client/server packets through TCP? You should have a good reason for that, otherwise go UDP.

Comment: If it requires authentication but further communication is not signed... then authentication does not seem so useful.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, it's a bit like logging on to SO and using it in plain HTTP afterwards...

Answer (score 3):

With the details you provided, it is difficult to give an absolute answer.

But here are some points you should have in mind:

- SSL induces an overhead; whether this overhead is significant/acceptable depends on many things. It is probably acceptable for a slow diplomacy simulation game, but likely not for a real-time first person shooter.
- SSL is not only about ciphering data, it is also about **authenticating** endpoints: that is, you know you are connecting to the requested server and not to some malicious server that wants to steal your password, and so on.
- SSL is also about avoiding replay attacks: depending on the game, being able to listen to network trafic and to replay it might be dangerous (as an example, an attacker could force you to repeat a "buy order")

Answer (score 2):

While I suppose you could (assuming that the game is communicating over TCP; with UDP you'd need a different approach to encryption anyway) it's hard to see why it is worthwhile doing for that sort of realtime data. The issue is that it ceases to be valuable to anyone at all very quickly.

That said, when communicating information that will persist (e.g., purchases in the “game store”) it is more important to encrypt and ensure the identity of who is doing it. That's the sort of thing that definitely should go over SSL (indeed, a RESTful webapp running over HTTPS would be an entirely reasonable way of implementing those parts). The key difference there is that the timing is less critical and the results persist.

Comment: For UDP, [DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Bruno: I failed to find any stable, well-documented and complete DTLS implementation in C++ that works. Do you have any link to share here ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You might want to encrypt confidential data like username, password, chat.
2. You might want to sign regular data, so others cannot tamper with that data (e.g. an attacker with a faster connection inserts some kind of 'move' into an existing connection or inserts spam into a chat connection). OpenSSL allows for that as well.